# Magento 1.9: How to limit collection for getPagerHtml?

Tags: magento-1.9

I want to limit the collection to display the page. For example, I search out 1000 products but want to limit to only 100 products.

Comment: try this: https://inchoo.net/magento/pagination-custom-collection/

Answer (score 0):

Please try with below code :
using `setAvailableLimit()` as

```
$pager->setAvailableLimit(array(4=>4,10=>10,20=>20,'all'=>'all')); // Now you can get 4 items in a page.
```

i.e, The first element in the array will be set the default limit for the collection (per page).